# Check if one array items contain in another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following two arrays and tried the following code but its returning `true` although it should return false:

```js
var myArray = [{
    "DealerId": "32",
    "AllowedProviders": "ATTv6,CENTURYLINK",
  },
  {
    "DealerId": "24",
    "AllowedProviders": "ACDNET",
  }
];

var providerArray = ["ATTv6", "ACDNET"];

var result = myArray.some(function(item) {
  return (item.AllowedProviders.split(',')).some(r => providerArray.includes(r)) 
          && item.DealerId != 32;
});

console.log(result);
```

I have 2 conditions to check;

1. If there is any item in myArray that  matches any of the items from `providerArray`.
2. If such item is found, then check if this items's `DealerId` is not equal to 32.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: It will return true since the second item has "ACDNET"? That item fits all the criteria, and therefore will return true, making the `some` return true

Comment: @Kobe so how can I check for dealerID for that item that fulfils the first condition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. It sounds as if you want to use `every` here instead of `some`?

Comment: @Kobe I want to check dealerID for the item that matches the first condition. This code reads dealerID of all items present in array. The first condition should have filtered the first item since it matched it, i want the second condition `item.DealerId != 32` to read the already filtered item from the first condition

Comment: Your code looks fine.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. You make the check that each of the objects contains one of the strings in the providerArray. **Both** items will pass this condition. Then only the first item fails the second condition, leaving the second item, meaning the some will return true.

Comment: Trying to understand what you want to do, it seems to me you want to *filter* your array. So instead of `myArray.some` you could use `myArray.filter`

Comment: @adiga basically i want to check both `AllowedProviders` and `DealerId` at the same time. So when it found ATTv6 in the first item whose `dealerid` was equal to 32, it should have returned false

Comment: @HumaAli You are looking to use `every`, then. You should make the second check first, instead, to allow for an early return, and improve performance so you don't have to split every time.

Comment: `myArray.every(function(item)` instead of `myArray.some(function(item)` does the trick.

Comment: @Kobe yes checked every. `The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function`. This will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want ***every*** item to pass the checks you have given. Therefore, you should use `every`, instead of `some`:

```js
var myArray = [{
    "DealerId": "32",
    "AllowedProviders": "ATTv6,CENTURYLINK",
  },
  {
    "DealerId": "24",
    "AllowedProviders": "ACDNET",
  }
];

var providerArray = ["ATTv6", "ACDNET"];

const result = myArray.every(i => i.DealerId !== '32' && providerArray.some(p => i.AllowedProviders.includes(p)))

console.log(result);
```

> Note, You should check the ID first, to prevent having to execute a more strenuous check only for it to be a useless check later. You should also make a string check, rather than a number check, as the ID is *not* a number.
>
> You can see the serious performance increase with a [test](https://jsperf.com/check-ordering/1):
>
> [image: JSPerf]